# Custom dropdown with GroceryCrud?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, grocery-crud

how can I add a custom dropdown with GroceryCrud? I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clients` (
  `clientId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cif` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clientId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the following code to show the functionality:

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->set_theme('datatables');
$crud->set_table('clients');
$crud->set_subject($this->lang->line('tpv_clients'));
$crud->display_as('clientName', $this->lang->line('tpv_client_name'));
$crud->display_as('cif', $this->lang->line('tpv_client_cif'));
$crud->display_as('address', $this->lang->line('tpv_client_address'));
$crud->display_as('type', $this->lang->line('tpv_client_type'));
$crud->columns('clientName','address','type');
$crud->required_fields('clientName', 'cif', 'type');
$output = $crud->render();
```

The field "type" should be only contain two values: "A" or "B". I need a dropdown combo with these two values. I have tried this code

```
$crud->field_type('type','dropdown',array('1' => 'A', '2' => 'B'));
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need this:

```
$crud->field_type('type','dropdown',array('A' => 'A', 'B' => 'B'));
```

For more about the field_type method, you can check: http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type

Comment: Yea it works! Yesterday it was failing because the grocery crud version was 1.2 ... Now I have upgraded to 1.4.1 and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your column as an ENUM:

> `type` ENUM('A','B') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: this is the most efficient way of doing it, just set the field in your database as ENUM and add all the values